# Writing traversals to a file in python3.x issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, heap, traversal

I am trying to traverse a heap, and write the traversal to a file but I am failing miserably.

I keep getting an issue with the maximum traversal depth that spams my terminal when all I want is for the node to be printed out in the file.

Comment: Why not make the file `j` an argument, rather than keep `open`ing it? Also, your check should be `is not None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited my code - they should be different files, one for each traversal

Comment: That's not what I mean; you reopen on each recursion, just open once outside and pass the file object in as an argument.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm afraid I don't understand.  I should place the with open above the function definition?

Comment: E.g. `def inorder(self, i):` then call it `with open(...) as i: instance.inorder(i)`

Comment: What Should I substitute for i in the main function when calling it?  The filename? or None?

Comment: No, the *file object*. Open it outside the call, pass it in to be written to. Read my example.

Comment: I see your answer but I am confused as to how to properly call it.  Could you perhaps improve my answer with what you mean and with the function call at the bottom?

Comment: It's too long for a comment but doesn't answer the question; don't worry about it.

Comment: I was hoping for a suggestion regarding writing to the file directly but that doesn't drag me way off course because I am working against a deadline and can't figure this part out.  It keeps quitting at max recursion depth instead of writing the nodes to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should look more like this:

```
def inorder(self, file):    
    if self._left is not None:
        file.write(str(self) + ' ')
        self._left.inorder(file)
    file.write(str(self) + ' ')
    if self._right is not None:
        file.write(str(self) + ' ')
        self._right.inorder(file)
```

Note that:

1. The `file` to write to is an argument, passed to the recursive calls, not `open`ed each time;
2. Testing for `None` by identity not equality; and
3. I am assuming that you have a tree structure where `self._left` and `self._right` are instances of the same class as `self` (as you've provided so little of the class, it's hard to be sure, but `self.inorder(self._left)` makes no sense).

When you call this, on some instance `instance` of your class, it would look like:

```
with open(...) as f:
    instance.inorder(f)
```